# Open web pages in desktop mode in Android webkit

Tags: android, webkit

You guys have any idea how to open web pages in desktop mode in android using webkit??

Comment: Desktop mode? Btw, you don't use webkit, you use WebView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html "The only classes or interfaces in this package intended for use by SDK developers are WebView, BroswerCallbackAdapter, BrowserCallback, and CookieManager."

Comment: hello james please explain what do you means by desktop mode ?

Comment: hi; webkit always opens the web pages in mobile format. I want to open the pages like my PC. I am using android 2.2 froyo.

Comment: Have you tried WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLayoutAlgorithm(android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgent(1);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think u wnt to open web page on android device.. if  yes thn you may use web view in android application and fetch page through URL...

Comment: -1, mostly because slang language/typing isn't a proper way to answer here on StackOverflow!